# Monotonic sequence (edited)

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, order-theory

For any two n-dim vector $v$ and $v'$ define $v\leq v'$ iff for each $1\leq i\leq n$, $v_i\leq v_i'$. 
Suppose further that the entry of vectors can only take values from $m$ distinct values $\{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_m\}$.

Claim: for a sequence of vectors $v_1\leq v_2 \leq \cdots \leq v_s$ for $s=mn+1$, we must have some $i,j$ such that $v_i=v_j$.

This seems to be trivial, but is there any formal and simple proof for that? Or does this follow from some famous theorem (e.g. some Erdos theorem)?

Comment: This does follow from a famous theorem, viz. Dirichlet principle (pigeonhole principal in American textbooks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the OP means that the values are ordered linearly, i.e. $a_1<\dots<a_m$. In that case the statement is even true for $s=mn-n+2$.

To see this, define the numbers $1\leq c(i,k)\leq m$ such that $v_i=(a_{c(i,1)},\dots,a_{c(i,n)})$. In addition, consider the integers $w_i:=c(i,1)+\dots+c(i,n)$. Then, for any pair $1\leq i<j\leq s$, we have $v_i\leq v_j$, hence $c(i,k)\leq c(j,k)$ for any $1\leq k\leq n$, hence also $w_i\leq w_j$. Moreover, $w_i=w_j$ can only hold when $c(i,k)=c(j,k)$ for each $1\leq k\leq n$, i.e. when $v_i=v_j$. 
Now observe that $n\leq w_1\leq\dots\leq w_s\leq mn$, hence for $s=mn-n+2$ we have $w_i=w_j$ for some $i<j$, so $v_i=v_j$ by the discussion above. The proof is complete.

Comment: you are right for the original formulation. However, I meant the current formulation. Sorry for that and thanks for your answer.

Comment: @maomao Since the problem is purely combinatorial, it doesn't really matter what the values are. Or, if you prefer, you can add them with weights.

Comment: yes. However, the improvement given by GH from MO does use values, doesn't it? So for the current formulation, the improvement does not hold, I think. Anyway, it is a very simple problem, and for some reason I thought the Erdos-Szekeres theorem can be applied here, but did not see exactly how. This was the main purpose of my question. Thanks.